# @PostConstruct not working in JBoss 5

Tags: servlets, jersey, postconstruct

I have a servlet that I cannot change ([`com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.goodwill/1.1.5/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.java) of Jersey RS) . What I can do is create a subclass of it. However, I needed that when the servlet is initialized it runs one function of my subclass. I cannot override the `init` method because it has the Jersey code.

I tried to use the annotation `@PostConstruct` on a method to make it run after initialization but it does not work (but it does work under Tomcat 6).
In `web.xml` the class is set to run on startup.

Comment: Why can't you override `init`?  The method isn't `final`, so what's the problem?

Comment: I ain't no Java expert, but I would need to copy the whole code from the existing source code to mine right? And also, the init(WebConfig webconfig) access a private attribute webComponent.

Comment: @No, no copying required. See my answer below. You may need to beef up your Java knowledge to tackle this, this is quite basic inheritance stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to subclass `ServletContainer`, override `init`, invoke the superclass method then perform your own logic, i.e.

```
public class MyServletContainer extends ServletContainer {

   public void init() throws ServletException {
      super.init();

      //... perform custom initialization logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: mother of dumbness :O Nothing to do here! I seldom have the need for inheritance and forget these kind of *basic* thing!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some of these jars "commons-annotation.jar, geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec, jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec" in your webapp lib and remove.